# How to use mercurial source control blame (annotate) functionality on IntelliJ IDEA project?

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea, blame

I just want to see who what the last who modified a specific line of code from inside IntelliJ IDEA (mercurial scm).

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't Annotate action work for you?
`Main Menu -> VCS -> Mercurial -> Annotate` or Click on gutter to the left of the editor and select `Annotate` there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Still it does not work, it does nothing (but line  # works). The second option was not checked, but the fist one was - still I do not see the names.

Comment: This should work.  I often just right click in the left margin and click 'Annotations.' It takes 10 seconds but then annotates all lines cleanly.